# Mathematica: using nest on a computation of multiple elements of the same list

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, nest

I am a physics student. I must perform a simple relaxation loop over a list of data
and i did it whith a simple while loop that looks something like this

```
i = 1;
While[i < Limit, 
data[[i]]  = f[ data[[i]] , data[[i+1]], data[[i-1]] ];
i = i+2;

i = 2;
While[i < Limit, 
data[[i]]  = f[ data[[i]] , data[[i+1]], data[[i-1]] ];
i = i+2;
```

as you can see, i perform the operation first on odd places of the list and then on even ones. The problem is, i must do this something like ten thousand times for the solution to converge and this takes too much time. So i was wondering if this could be accomplished in a faster way maybe using nest, but how can i use data[[i+1]] and data[[i-1]] in the computation?

Maybe it is a trivial question so i apologize in advance,

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should note that relaxation method is inherently slow by its nature. So don't expect to get ultra fast results using it. There are other(extremely faster) methods for real life problems.

Anyway, I have a couple of suggestions which may kick your performance by a couple of factors.

**First:** I think think the function `f` should be simple enough to compile it; so do it! I think something like

```
f=Compile[{{a,_Real},{b,_Real},{c,Real}},"Write f[a,b,c] explicitly",CompilationTarget->"C"]
```

Should work.

**Second:** Try to use `FixedPoint`. In order to do so, I would probably do something like(or maybe something slightly better :-):

```
g[data,_List]:=Block[{i = 1},
    While[i < Length[data], 
    data[[i]]  = f[ data[[i]] , data[[i+1]], data[[i-1]] ];
    i = i+2;
    ]
    i = 2;
    While[i < Length[data], 
    data[[i]]  = f[ data[[i]] , data[[i+1]], data[[i-1]] ];
    i = i+2;
    data];
FixedPoint[g,"initialdata",SameTest->((#1-#2).(#1-#2)<10^(-4)&)]
```

Also, you have to take care of the boundary conditions yourself.

Answer (score 0):

This operation can probably be done easily using *Mathematica's* list-oriented functions, but I can't quite tell what you want because your code is incomplete (syntax errors, and missing data).

You should look at these functions: [`Partition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Partition.html), [`MovingAverage`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/MovingAverage.html), [`ListCorrelate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ListCorrelate.html), [`FoldList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FoldList.html).

Here are a couple of possible interpretations.  ListCorrelate:

```
data = CharacterRange["a", "i"];

ListCorrelate[{1, 1, 1}, data, {1, -1}, {}, Times, f]
```

> ```
> {f[a,b,c],f[b,c,d],f[c,d,e],f[d,e,f],f[e,f,g],f[f,g,h],f[g,h,i]}
> ```

Partition and Riffle:

```
Riffle[Take[data, {1, -1, 2}], f @@@ Partition[data, 3, 2]]
```

> ```
> {a,f[a,b,c],c,f[c,d,e],e,f[e,f,g],g,f[g,h,i],i}
> ```

---

You may get better answers if you follow the [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) principle and ask your questions here:

[image]